# Cloned HDD won't boot neither will the original

Tags: cloning

I tried cloning for the first time using Macrium Reflect.  The clone seemed to go okay but when I tried to boot from the new HDD nothing would happen, I would just get a blank screen.  So I put back my original HDD and tried cloning again. This time it seemed to work as my new HDD booted but the problem was it took about 5 minutes to load which was way too long as it is a relatively new computer. So I restarted my computer but after the restart the new HDD wouldn't boot anymore.  I would just get a blank screen.

I put back my original HDD but now that won't boot anymore as well.  I keep getting a blank screen, I can't even seem to boot into the Bios since nothing appears on the screen.

Can anyone shed some light on what might have happened? Is there a way I can fix this and get my HDD back up and running again?

Comment: Did you knock something loose while in the PC? Check all connections with power cord removed.